# Traverse the DOM with this Tree Traversal? help JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to traverse the DOM to select .faq-answer and show it on the click on .faq-question a. I think I need to use "this" but I don't know what to do next.

```
                    <div class="faq-question">
                        <?php
                        // display a sub field value
                            echo '<p>Question: </p>';
                            the_sub_field('faq_question');
                        ?>
                        <a href="#" class="";></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="faq-answer"">
                        <?php
                        // display a sub field value
                            echo '<div class="faq-answer-answer">';
                            echo '<p>Answer: </p>';
                                the_sub_field('faq_answer');
                            echo '</div>';
                        ?>
                        <a href="#" class="";></a>
                    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".faq-answer").hide();

        $( ".faq-question a" ).click(function() {
            $( ".faq-answer" ).toggle( "slide" );
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `.faq-answer` is the immediate next following sibling element of the `.faq-question`, you can use `parent()` to get to the question div, then `next()` to get to the answer div:

```
$( ".faq-question a" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle( "slide" );
});
```

That's obviously a bit fragile; small changes to the HTML will break it. We can mitigate that using `closest` for the first bit instead of `parent()`:

```
$( ".faq-question a" ).click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".faq-question").next().toggle( "slide" );
});
```

And similarly, if you might want to slip an element between the question and answer, we can make the second part (`next()`) a bit less fragile as well by finding the first next matching element:

```
$( ".faq-question a" ).click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".faq-question").nextAll(".faq-answer").first().toggle( "slide" );
    // Find all following answers ---^                      ^
    // Take the first one (they'll be in order) ------------|
});
```

When *possible* (it isn't, always), I like to use a container element around related items like this:

```
<div class="qa-container">
    <div class="faq-question">
        <?php
        // display a sub field value
            echo '<p>Question: </p>';
            the_sub_field('faq_question');
        ?>
        <a href="#" class="";></a>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-answer"">
        <?php
        // display a sub field value
            echo '<div class="faq-answer-answer">';
            echo '<p>Answer: </p>';
                the_sub_field('faq_answer');
            echo '</div>';
        ?>
        <a href="#" class="";></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each question and answer pair would be wrapped in a `.qa-container`. Then it's much more robust:

```
$( ".faq-question a" ).click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".qa-container").find(".faq-answer").toggle( "slide" );
});
```

Comment: WOW great post! by the way do you know why my reputation went down? I am still new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @user3562836 Your reputation went down because of the downvotes to your previous question. see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)